# Identifier not found.C3861

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors, identifier

I have a file "HSlider.h" it is using "Draw.h",where I defined my functions to use them .
But compiler says I havent defined them(identificator not found).I searched forums for similiar error,but it didnt help.

**I am working in VS 2015 Communty .**

**ERROR EXAMPLE:
Error C3861 DrawGUIBox: identifier not found
Try2 c:\users\lel\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\try2\try2\hslider.h 50
.**

**HSlider.h**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <conio.h>
#include "Offsets.h"

#include "Draw.h"
using namespace std;


class Button
{
public:
    void Init(float _x, float _y, float _w, float _h, int _r, int _g, int _b, int _a, int _rr, int _gg, int _bb, int _aa,int _onr,int _ong,int _onb)
    {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        w = _w;
        h = _h;
        r = _r;
        g = _g;
        b = _b;
        a = _a;
        rr = _rr;
        gg = _gg;
        bb = _bb;
        aa = _aa;
        onr = _onr;
        onb = _onb;
        ong = _ong;

    }
    void Move(float _x, float _y)
    {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }
    void Update(int _bindb)
    {
        BindB = _bindb;
        DrawGUIBox(x, y, w, h, r, g, b, a, rr, gg, bb, aa);
        POINT p;
        GetCursorPos(&p);

        if ((p.x > x&&p.x<x + w&&p.y>y&&p.y < y + h))
        {
            if ((GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)&1 ))
            {
                On = !On;

            }



        }
        if ((GetAsyncKeyState(BindB)&1 ))
        {
            On = !On;
        }
        if (On)
        {
            DrawGUIBox(x, y, w, h, r, g, b, a, onr,ong,onb, a);
        }

    }
    bool Extract()
    {
        return On;
    }
    void Off()
    {
        On = false;
    }
private:
    float x;
    float y;
    float w;
    float h;
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
    int a;
    int rr;
    int gg;
    int bb;
    int aa;
    int onr;
    int ong;
    int onb;
    int BindB;
    bool On = false;
    bool IsUP = true;
};
```

**Draw.h**

```
  #pragma once
    #ifndef HDRAWFUNC_H
    #define HDRAWFUNC_H

    #include "DirectX.h"

    #pragma warning( disable : 4244 ) //remove the incoming warns
    #pragma warning( disable : 4996 ) //remove the incoming warns

    #include <d3dx9.h>
    #include <d3d9.h>
    #define D3DFVF_TL (D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE | D3DFVF_TEX1)
    #pragma comment(lib, "d3d9.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib, "d3dx9.lib")
    static struct D3DTLVERTEX;
    void GradientFunc(int x, int y, int w, int h, int r, int g, int b, int a);
    void DrawCenterLine(float x, float y, int r, int g, int b, int a);
    void DrawLine(float x, float y, float xx, float yy, int r, int g, int b, int a);
    void DrawCursorLine(float x, float y, float xx, float yy, int r, int g, int b, int a);
    void FillRGB(float x, float y, float w, float h, int r, int g, int b, int a);
    void DrawBox(float x, float y, float width, float height, float px, int r, int g, int b, int a);
    void DrawGUIBox(float x, float y, float w, float h, int r, int g, int b, int a, int rr, int gg, int bb, int aa);
    void DrawHealthBar(float x, float y, float w, float h, int r, int g, int b);
    void DrawHealthBarBack(float x, float y, float w, float h);
    void DrawGroupBox(float x, float y, float w, float h, int r, int g, int b, int a, int rr, int gg, int bb, int aa, char* title);
    int DrawString(char* String, int x, int y, int r, int g, int b, ID3DXFont* ifont);
    int DrawShadowString(char* String, int x, int y, int r, int g, int b, ID3DXFont* ifont);
    void DrawCircle(int x, int y, float radius, int Sides, D3DCOLOR color);
    D3DTLVERTEX CreateD3DTLVERTEX(float X, float Y, float Z, float RHW, D3DCOLOR color, float U, float V);
    void DrawFilledCircle(int xPos, int yPos, int Radius, D3DCOLOR color);
    void FillARGBTriangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3, D3DCOLOR color, IDirect3DDevice9 *pDevice);
    #endif
```

And whole project if you need it. https://yadi.sk/d/uOPt8pdC3Jb78o

Comment: `#pragma once` + `#ifndef HDRAWFUNC_H`/`#define HDRAWFUNC_H`/`#endif` is redundant.

Comment: I can't find the text Try2 in hslider.h

Comment: You mean font?Try2 is the name of a project.Font is in DirectX.cpp.

Comment: Assuming this is the real code, line 50 is `On = !On;`. Perhaps there is a `#define On` in some other part of the code you didn't post.  To test this you could try `#ifdef On`  `#error On is defined` `#endif` and see if you get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer myself.
The problem was in circular inclusion.
And it occured because  I defined my classes in header file instead of .cpp file.
After doing that and moving headers correctly I fixed it in a matter of minutes.

Moral:Never break c++ rules.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your source code. The problem is that your Visual Studio solution file (in the link you posted) has become corrupted. In the solution file there are references to a project called Try2, but this project does not exist in the solution.

To fix this, do the following.

Open the Help.sln file with notepad++, and you will see there is a line

```
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "Try2", "Try2\Try2.vcxproj", "{BC659ABD-F853-4678-83AF-3D29339A7FC0}"
```

This means that there is meant to be a sub-project called Try2, but it doesn't exist. In your archive, the sub-project is actually called "Help". So, change the line to:

```
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "Help", "Help\Help.vcxproj", "{BC659ABD-F853-4678-83AF-3D29339A7FC0}"
```

After that, go through the x64 folders in your solution and remove any residual files that refer to Try2.

OR, create a new empty solution and copy your .cpp and .h source files (only) one at a time into the new solution.

(There is also a separate problem where the Offsets.h file is missing, but I can't help with that.)